# Delete temporary internet files on a terminal server (Server 2003)

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

Are there any apps or scripts that will remove all temporary internet files for all users on a windows 2003 terminal server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a create a script or use a [group policy](http://www.petri.co.il/controlling_ie_cache_size_via_gpo.htm) to set the cache size.  Set it to 0 and the files will not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

run the disk cleanup tool from the logoff script.  See [Automating Disk Cleanup Tool in Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/253597) for details on how to save and set options so you are not running the whole wizard every time (just temporary internet files)